# this.props.navigation is undefined when using DrawerNavigator

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

I'm integrating DrawerNavigator of `'react-navigation'` to my project as [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/drawer) document. But when I run the project it always get this error when click on the Button:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'this.props.navigation.navigate')

And when I swipe from left to right, nothing happen, no drawer open.

I've check `this.props` and it's always log empty `{}` in console.
I tried many solutions but it's still not working.

**calculator.js**

```
export default class Calculator extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    static navigationOptions = {
        drawerLabel: 'Calculator',
        drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
            <Image
                source={require('./../../res/images/icon_calculator.png')}
                style={[styles.icon, {tintColor: tintColor}]}
            />
        ),
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View>
                    <Text style={styles.title}>Tip Calculator</Text>
                </View>
                <Button
                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("SettingsScreen")}
                    title="Go to settings"
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

module.exports = Calculator;
```

**settings.js**

```
export default class Settings extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    static navigationOptions = {
        drawerLabel: 'Settings',
        drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
            <Image
                source={require('./../../res/images/icon_settings.png')}
                style={[styles.icon, {tintColor: tintColor}]}
            />
        ),
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>Settings</Text>
                <Button
                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}
                    title="Go back home"
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

module.exports = Settings;
```

**navigation.js**

```
import {
    DrawerNavigator
} from 'react-navigation';
import Calculator from './../components/calculator/calculator.js';
import Settings from './../components/settings/settings.js';


const RootDrawer = DrawerNavigator({
    CalculatorScreen: {
        path: '/',
        screen: Calculator
    },
    SettingsScreen: {
        path: '/sent',
        screen: Settings
    }
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'CalculatorScreen',
    drawerPosition: 'left'
});

export default RootDrawer;
```

**App.js**

```
export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <Calculator/>
    );
  }
}
```

**index.js**

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('rn_tip_calculator', () => App);
```

Do I have to use `StackNavigator` with `DrawerNavigator`, or am I missed something in config?

Full source code, it's only a simple example project, please have a look: https://github.com/HCMUS-IceTeaViet-SE/rn_tip_calculator

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Its because you're not "connecting" or mounting navigation to the app. Before it wasn't being passed to app because Of a typo I believe I found here...https://github.com/HCMUS-IceTeaViet-SE/rn_tip_calculator/blob/master/app/powerranger.js

the navigator you pass through on line 25 is lower case, shouldn't it have been Uppercase?

Comment: @GavinThomas So I must change AppRegistry to register my DrawerNavigator instead of App component in app.js? Why? What happen if I register them both?

Comment: You can't and shouldn't render them both. You should render your App then import RootDrawer into App, then pass it through into calculator. I will look tomorrow for sure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happen because I don't "connect" my DrawerNavigator to my app.

There is 2 ways to achieve this:

- First way: register DrawerNavigator as app root component. In `index.js` change:

  from `AppRegistry.registerComponent('rn_tip_calculator', () => App);`

  to `AppRegistry.registerComponent('rn_tip_calculator', () => RootDrawer);`

  So you could delete `App.js` because it's useless now.
- Second way: Keep register `App` component (in App.js) as app root component. Then put  inside `App` component to "connect" DrawerNavigator to the app.

  ```
  export default class App extends Component<{}> {
    render() {
      return (
        <RootDrawer/>
      );
    }
  }
  ```

The [document](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/drawer) say nothing about how to connect the navigator to the app, nothing about register component or put navigator inside root component. This drive newbie like me mad!

Answer (score 1):

You can use dispatch api https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-actions

1) import navigation actions

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'
```

2) dispatch navigation action:

```
const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
    routeName: 'SettingsScreen',
    params: {},
})

this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction)
```

Comment: Ok I will try, but why my code not work? It's the same as the document

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty new to React-Native but sometimes this also happens to me.

I'm using Redux and stack navigator.... but here is my working example...

```
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
import { Animated, Easing } from 'react-native'
import LoginScreen from '../Containers/LoginScreen'
import LaunchScreen from '../Containers/LaunchScreen'
import HomeScreen from '../Containers/HomeScreen'
import SignUpScreen from '../Containers/SignUpScreen'
import SettingsScreen from '../Containers/SettingsScreen'
import VehicleCreateScreen from '../Containers/VehicleCreateScreen'
import styles from './Styles/NavigationStyles'

// Manifest of possible screens
const PrimaryNav = StackNavigator({
  LoginScreen: { screen: LoginScreen },
  LaunchScreen: { screen: LaunchScreen },
  HomeScreen: { screen: HomeScreen },
  SignUpScreen: { screen: SignUpScreen },
  SettingsScreen: { screen: SettingsScreen },
  VehicleCreateScreen: { screen: VehicleCreateScreen }
}, {
    // Default config for all screens
    headerMode: 'none',
    initialRouteName: 'LaunchScreen',
    navigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: styles.header
    },
    transitionSpec: {
      duration: 0,
      timing: Animated.timing,
      easing: Easing.step0,
    },
  },


)

export default PrimaryNav
```

And then from a component not connected to REDUX

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Content, List, ListItem, Icon, Text, Button, Left, Right, Badge } from 'native-base';
import { Image } from 'react-native'
import styles from './Styles/SideBarStyle';
// import backgroundImage from '../Images/vw.jpg'

const backgroundImage = require("../Images/vw.jpg");
const drawerImage = require("../Images/dirtyHandsDark.jpg");


export default class SideBar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        // *********** HERE WE DECLARE AN ARRAY TO RENDER LISTS FROM. THIS COULD ALSO BE LIST OF BIKES FROM STORE.. ***********
        const datas = [
            {
                name: "Home",
                route: "HomeScreen",
                icon: "settings",
                bg: "#C5F442",
            },
            {
                name: "Repair",
                route: "HomeScreen",
                icon: "settings",
                bg: "#C5F442",
            },
            {
                name: "My Profile",
                route: "SettingsScreen",
                icon: "settings",
                bg: "#C5F442",
            },

        ];


        return (
            <Container>
                <Content bounces={false} style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#fff", top: -1 }}>
                    <Image source={backgroundImage} style={styles.drawerCover}>
                        <Image square style={styles.drawerImage} source={drawerImage} />
                    </Image>
                    <List
                        dataArray={datas}
                        renderRow={data =>
                            // *********** CREATE NEW LIST ITEM ON CLICK NAVIGATE TO APPROPRIATE LISTITEM.SCREEN ***********
                            <ListItem button noBorder onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate(data.route)}>
                                <Left>
                                    <Icon active name={data.icon} style={{ color: "#777", fontSize: 26, width: 30 }} />
                                    <Text style={styles.text}>
                                        {data.name}
                                    </Text>
                                </Left>
                                {data.types &&
                                    <Right style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                                        <Badge
                                            style={{
                                                borderRadius: 3,
                                                height: 25,
                                                width: 72,
                                                backgroundColor: data.bg,
                                            }}
                                        >
                                            <Text style={styles.badgeText}>{`${data.types} Types`}</Text>
                                        </Badge>
                                    </Right>}
                            </ListItem>}
                    />
                </Content>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

You can see I reference this.props.navigation.navigate no problem. 
Heres my repo for reference. 
https://github.com/GavinThomas1192/motoMechanicMeeKanic/tree/master/App

Comment: Thanks for answer my question! I tried your solution but it caused "Can't find variable: navigate"

Comment: WHOOPS I shouldn't have used DidUPdate, use componentDidMount

Comment: Still not working tho, I've update `app.js` and `index.js` of my project, can you have a look?

Comment: Also in your app.js what is <{}> doing after extends Component?

Comment: try to pass navigation through your Calculator component
 <Calculator navigation={this.props.navigation}/>

Comment: it's default when create app with react-native init. I tried pass `<Calculator navigation={this.props.navigation}/> ` but this.props of App only have `{rootTag: 101}` so `this.props.navigation` is undefined.

My source code: https://github.com/HCMUS-IceTeaViet-SE/rn_tip_calculator

Comment: It's working when I change my `index.js` to `AppRegistry.registerComponent('rn_tip_calculator', () => RootDrawer);` but I don't know why?